# find the max count in a subgroup

Tags: sql, pivot, amazon-redshift, aggregate-functions

I have a table (simplified)

[image]

I need to produce a report like this:

[image]

I need to find per user: total servers, total events, total succeeded and failed events. All this per user so I will be grouping by user.

But I'm also asked to compute the max number of events per single server per customer, i.e. subgrouping by server within each user. How do I do that?

Comment: You absolutely should add sample data to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with two levels of aggregation: first by user and server, then by user only.

```
select user_id, 
    count(*)          total_servers,
    sum(total_events) total_events,
    sum(succeeded)    succeeded,
    sum(failed)       failed,        
    max(total_events) max_per_server
from (
    select userid, server, 
        count(*) total_events,
        sum(case when event_status = 'success' then 1 else 0 end) succeeded,
        sum(case when event_status = 'success' then 1 else 0 end) failed
    from mytable t
    group by userid, server
) t
group by user_id
```

This should scan the table only once, and hence is likely to perform more efficiently than solutions involving joining CTEs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTE and calculate  (user) level and  (user,server) level seperately and join them to get the result you want.

Here is the query:

```
With user_attri AS (
SELECT
    userid,
    count(distinct server) as total_servers,
    count(1) as total_events,
    sum(case when event_status = 'success' then 1 else 0 end) as total_succeeded_events,
    sum(case when event_status = 'fail' then 1 else 0 end) as total_failed_events
from
    data_table
group by
    userid
),
user_server_attri AS (
select
     userid,
     server,
     count(1) as total_events
from
    data_table
group by
    userid,
    server
)
select
    ua.userid,
    ua.total_servers,
    ua.total_events,
    ua.total_succeeded_events,
    ua.total_failed_events,
    usa.max_per_server_events
from
    user_attri ua
JOIN (
    select 
        userid, 
        max(total_events) as max_per_server_events 
    from user_server_attri
    group by userid
    ) usa
on
    ua.userid= usa.userid
```